# Implementation of maximum in haskell

Tags: haskell

I was just looking up the implementation of the maximum function in haskell:

```
maximum :: forall a . Ord a => t a -> a
maximum = fromMaybe (errorWithoutStackTrace "maximum: empty structure") .
   getMax . foldMap (Max #. (Just :: a -> Maybe a))
```

Could somebody explain this piece of code to me?

In particular it is not clear to me how this part

```
Max #. (Just :: a -> Maybe a)
```

works. What does #. mean? To me it looks like something similar to function composition but typing

```
:t #.
```

in the REPL gives an error.
Also I think the argument for foldMap should be of the form

```
Monoid m => a -> m
```

But I can't see where the monoid structure comes from here.

Comment: The monoid structure comes from `Max`

Comment: see http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/src/Data.Foldable.html#%23.

Comment: And [Max](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/src/Data.Foldable.html#Max)

Comment: `(#.)` is just an optimized version of the composition operator `(.)` which only works in some cases, such as in `Max . Just`. Pretend it's plain composition, and note that `Max a` is a monoid with binary "max" for its operation (roughly, there's a `Maybe` wrapper so that we can define the unity to be `Nothing`).

Comment: you'll need the `MagicHash` extension for (`#.`) to be syntactically valid, and then you'll need to import it from wherever it's exposed

Comment: @jberryman, no you don't. But you need `:t (#.)`, not `:t #.`. And it's normally imported from `Data.Profunctor.Unsafe`, but `Data.Foldable` has its own specialized copy.

Comment: @dfeuer that doesn't work either on my machine...

Comment: @user3726947, you're going to have to be a lot more specific about what error you get.

Comment: it tells me: not in scope '#.' perhaps you meant '.'

Comment: If you have the `profunctors` package installed, you need to import `Data.Profunctor.Unsafe` (like I mentioned). If not, you should consider installing it.

Comment: ah ok now it works, I thought it suffices to import Data.Foldable

Answer (score 4):

`#.` is an operator that can make coercions easier to use.

```
f #. g
```

means

> `g`, coerced to the type of `f . g`

Similarly,

```
f .# g
```

means

> `f`, coerced to the type of `f . g`

In most cases, `f #. g` only makes sense if `f` is some combination of newtype constructors, newtype accessors, and `fmap`.

The reason for using `#.` in `maximum` us probably over-zealousness on my part. It can almost certainly be replaced with `.` without any problem.